# Read nested rapidjson in c++

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I tried something like

```
rapidjson::Value& response = Doc[level1][level2][level3]...

for (auto m=response.MemberBegin();m!=response.MemberEnd();++m)
{
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: you can take a look at this dart package here https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have tried serializing or deserializing JSON payload, that should be a good start. However, if you are having trouble getting a good sense what your models would look like for complex one, you try  pasting the JSON payload [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).

**models.dart**

```dart
class Response {
  List<Items> items;

  Response({this.items});

  Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['items'] != null) {
      items = new List<Items>();
      json['items'].forEach((v) {
        items.add(new Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.items != null) {
      data['items'] = this.items.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Items {
  String timestamp;
  List<CarparkData> carparkData;

  Items({this.timestamp, this.carparkData});

  Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    timestamp = json['timestamp'];
    if (json['carpark_data'] != null) {
      carparkData = new List<CarparkData>();
      json['carpark_data'].forEach((v) {
        carparkData.add(new CarparkData.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['timestamp'] = this.timestamp;
    if (this.carparkData != null) {
      data['carpark_data'] = this.carparkData.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class CarparkData {
  List<CarparkInfo> carparkInfo;
  String carparkNumber;
  String updateDatetime;

  CarparkData({this.carparkInfo, this.carparkNumber, this.updateDatetime});

  CarparkData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['carpark_info'] != null) {
      carparkInfo = new List<CarparkInfo>();
      json['carpark_info'].forEach((v) {
        carparkInfo.add(new CarparkInfo.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    carparkNumber = json['carpark_number'];
    updateDatetime = json['update_datetime'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.carparkInfo != null) {
      data['carpark_info'] = this.carparkInfo.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['carpark_number'] = this.carparkNumber;
    data['update_datetime'] = this.updateDatetime;
    return data;
  }
}

class CarparkInfo {
  String totalLots;
  String lotType;
  String lotsAvailable;

  CarparkInfo({this.totalLots, this.lotType, this.lotsAvailable});

  CarparkInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    totalLots = json['total_lots'];
    lotType = json['lot_type'];
    lotsAvailable = json['lots_available'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['total_lots'] = this.totalLots;
    data['lot_type'] = this.lotType;
    data['lots_available'] = this.lotsAvailable;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Although these models are already generated for you, it's best if you can check whether **each** field corresponds to their appropriate **data type** and **field name**.

There are different strategies in serializing and deserializing JSON payload. This is the most basic one, but should be fine for smaller projects with small teams. Flutter team created a well-written [document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) to help you identify what suites your need.

Furthermore, these resources should help you out:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json
- https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-json-array-and-json-object
- [DEMO] https://github.com/joshuadeguzman/flutter-examples/flutter_moviehub

Answer (score 2):

Your json response class should be like for serialize and deserialize

```
class ResponseData {
  List<Item> items;

  ResponseData({
    this.items,
  });

  factory ResponseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      ResponseData(
        items: List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        "items": List<dynamic>.from(items.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Item {
  DateTime timestamp;
  List<CarparkDatum> carparkData;

  Item({
    this.timestamp,
    this.carparkData,
  });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      Item(
        timestamp: DateTime.parse(json["timestamp"]),
        carparkData: List<CarparkDatum>.from(
            json["carpark_data"].map((x) => CarparkDatum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        "timestamp": timestamp.toIso8601String(),
        "carpark_data": List<dynamic>.from(carparkData.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class CarparkDatum {
  List<CarparkInfo> carparkInfo;
  String carparkNumber;
  DateTime updateDatetime;

  CarparkDatum({
    this.carparkInfo,
    this.carparkNumber,
    this.updateDatetime,
  });

  factory CarparkDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      CarparkDatum(
        carparkInfo: List<CarparkInfo>.from(
            json["carpark_info"].map((x) => CarparkInfo.fromJson(x))),
        carparkNumber: json["carpark_number"],
        updateDatetime: DateTime.parse(json["update_datetime"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        "carpark_info": List<dynamic>.from(carparkInfo.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "carpark_number": carparkNumber,
        "update_datetime": updateDatetime.toIso8601String(),
      };
}

class CarparkInfo {
  String totalLots;
  LotType lotType;
  String lotsAvailable;

  CarparkInfo({
    this.totalLots,
    this.lotType,
    this.lotsAvailable,
  });

  factory CarparkInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      CarparkInfo(
        totalLots: json["total_lots"],
        lotType: lotTypeValues.map[json["lot_type"]],
        lotsAvailable: json["lots_available"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        "total_lots": totalLots,
        "lot_type": lotTypeValues.reverse[lotType],
        "lots_available": lotsAvailable,
      };
}

enum LotType { C, H, Y, L }

final lotTypeValues = EnumValues({
  "C": LotType.C,
  "H": LotType.H,
  "L": LotType.L,
  "Y": LotType.Y
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always import the dart:convert package and use the json.decode function.

Answer (score 0):

just use this website to convert your json response to dart class

[json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

I highly recommend to use [json serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) for such things.

Here are good tutorial for network calling

[fetch data from internet flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

[handling network like a pro](https://medium.com/flutter-community/handling-network-calls-like-a-pro-in-flutter-31bd30c86be1)